# Jvm settings for Azure databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

As part performance one suggestion in spark documentation is to make pointers 4 bytes instead of 8 as shown in the figure.[image]

I'm working on Azure databricks. Now where do I add this config?

I tried adding in advanced options of a cluster under spark config, the following parameter:

```
jvm -XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

I'm I adding this config in right location? If not where should I add?

Edit:
Document link
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html

Comment: Could you please share the link of the document, which you are referring to?

Comment: Added the document link

Comment: Thanks for sharing the doc link.

Answer (score 0):

Edit Databricks cluster. Go to `Advanced` options below and then to `Environment variables`. Add there:

```sh
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseCompressedOops"
```

Please notice that there is some example, when you start to create a brand new cluster.